# Data values not showing in json

Tags: php, json, jsonp, highcharts

I have a problem with my script, its not showing a graph and data on it
Searched all over the forum and could not find the answer
Providing you with the codes i use for my project

This is my js code:

```
$(function() {
$.getJSON('http://store.steamaccounts.me/test/jsonp.php?filename=test.json&callback=?', function(data) {

    // Create the chart
    window.chart = new Highcharts.StockChart({
        chart : {
            renderTo : 'container'
        },

        rangeSelector : {
            selected : 1
        },

        title : {
            text : 'test'
        },

        series : [{
            name : 'test',
            data : data,
            type : 'area',
            threshold : null,
            tooltip : {
                valueDecimals : 2
            },
            fillColor : {
                linearGradient : {
                    x1: 0, 
                    y1: 0, 
                    x2: 0, 
                    y2: 1
                },
                stops : [[0, Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]], [1, 'rgba(0,0,0,0)']]
            }
        }]
    });
});
```

And this is my php code:

```
<?php

$data = '{}'; // json string

if(array_key_exists('callback', $_GET)){

    header('Content-Type: text/javascript; charset=utf8');


    $callback = $_GET['callback'];
    echo $callback.'('.$data.');';

}else{
    // normal JSON string
    header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf8');

    echo $data;
}
```

I would appreciate any help with this
Thank you for a quick reply

Comment: Should you be returning something other than an empty object in your JSON serialization?

Answer (score 0):

As of JQuery 1.4 it says if your JSON file contains an error then the method getJSON silently fails.
Just in case should it be better to check the returned JSON  data.

Answer (score 0):

As I see your data is empty, so please ensure if you get any values.

Answer (score -1):

I think the problem might lie in the fact that the variable `$data` is never being changed from an empty json object `{}`. You can create a json string with the php function `json_encode`.

`json_encode` accepts an array as input and converts it to a json compliant object stored as a string.

Then you can echo the string to return to the browser.

Comment: `json_encode` just makes a string on JSON serializatoion format. His `$data` variable (the string - `{}`) IS a valid JSON serialization.

Comment: @MikeBrant I know, I was just informing him of a way to create a json string using variables without extensive and messy string manipulation just in case he needed it if he were to change his code to output something besides an empty json object.